# Snapshotting on google cloud/Kubernetes when using storageClass persistent volumes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

[StorageClasses](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#storageclasses) are the new method of specifying dynamic `persistent volume claim` (PVC) dependencies within Kubernetes. This avoids the need to explicitly provision one directly with the cloud provider (in my case Google Container Engine (GKE)).

Definition for the `StorageClasses` (GKE already has a default for `standard` class)

```
---
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: fast
provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
parameters:
  type: pd-ssd
  zone: europe-west1-b
```

Definition for the actual PVC

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: nfs-server-pvc
  namespace: staging
spec:
  accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Gi
  storageClassName: "standard"
```

Here is the result of `kubernetes get storageclass`:

```
NAME                 TYPE
fast                 kubernetes.io/gce-pd
standard (default)   kubernetes.io/gce-pd
```

Here is the result of `kubernetes get pvc`:

```
NAME             STATUS    VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESSMODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
nfs-pvc          Bound     nfs                                        1Mi        RWX                          119d
nfs-server-pvc   Bound     pvc-905a810b-3f13-11e7-82f9-42010a840072   100Gi      RWO           standard       81d
```

I would like to continue taking snapshots of the volumes but the dynamic nature of the `volume` names created (in this case `pvc-905a810b-3f13-11e7-82f9-42010a840072`), mean i cannot continue with the following command that i had been using via cron (note the "nfs" name is now incorrect):

```
gcloud compute --project "XXX-XXX" disks snapshot "nfs" --zone "europe-west1-b" --snapshot-names "nfs-${DATE}"
```

I guess this boils down to Kubernetes allowing explicit naming through StorageClass-based PVC. The [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#storageclasses) don't seem to allow this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to manually create the PV and give it a stable name that you can use in your scripts. You can use gcloud commands to create the underlying PD disks.  When you create the PV, give it a label:

```
apiVersion: "v1"
kind: "PersistentVolume"
metadata:
  name: my-pv-0
  labels:
    pdName: my-pv-0
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: "10Gi"
  accessModes:
    - "ReadWriteOnce"
  storageClassName: fast
  gcePersistentDisk:
    fsType: "ext4"
    pdName: "my-pd-0"
```

Then attach it to the PVC using a selector:

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-pvc-0
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
  storageClassName: fast
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      pdName:  my-pv-0
```

Comment: Wouldn't you be then declaring the PV details twice though through the gcloud command and the k8s manifests. Is there a way to attach a selector through k8s alone?

Comment: I may have misunderstand what you are trying to accomplish. I think you want to have stable and well known volume names that you can script automated snapshots. The approach above will let you do that.  The Kubernetes auto-provisioner generates unique names that you can not control. There is a proposal to add volume snapshots in the future as a native kubernetes feature.

Comment: Think this is the crux of the matter yes. It does really diminish the appeal of the storageclass abstraction.